# How to override the default method in CanCanCan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authorization, cancancan

CanCanCan makes two assumptions about the application:

1*An Ability class which defines the permissions.

2*A current_user method in the controller which returns the current user model.

In my case, i have two models object and subject (I can create, update, destroy) both of them using CRUD operations.

Now i want to restrict access to this object using CanCanCan library authorization. I know that CanCanCan expects a current_user method to exist in the controller and set up some authentication (like Devise). How can i override the default method that expects a current_user and pass it a current_subject, since that one shoud have access to object.

Comment: just create an aliased method in the controlelr pointing to current_subject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Use an alias to the new helper method:

Simply alias the current_user helper method in the controller to the actual helper method that you are using:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  alias_method :current_user, :current_subject # or whatever your helper method is called - this is untested btw
end

# Source: https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/changing-defaults
```